# Multiple C++ deletion of a memory pointed by multiple objects

Tags: c++, memory, delete-operator

Another C++ pointer deletion question is in the following example:

```
class Foo {
public:
    int *p;
    ~Foo() {
        delete p; p = NULL;
    }
};

Foo *f1 = new Foo();
Foo *f2 = new Foo();
f1->p = new int(1);
f2->p = f1->p;
delete f2; // ok
delete f1; // no error?
```

Why I did not get error when calling "delete f1"? didn't I delete the same address (*p) twice?

If I directly delete the pointers in the last 2 lines of code, I will get error.

```
delete f2->p; // ok
delete f1->p; // error!! *** glibc detected *** double free or corruption (fasttop) ***
```

Comment: Comment on style: `delete p; p = NULL;` Setting the pointer to NULL in a destructor is a waste of time. Also in general setting a pointer to NULL after deleting is not considered a good idea as you will hide potential coding errors in your code. By hiding them you will stop standard tools from picking up these errors (it may save time in the short run but in the long run it will do more harm).

Comment: @Martin York: Good advice but in some case (not a destructor) you may want to free some member and setting it to `NULL` is good way of telling that it doesn't longer exist.

Comment: Because "undefined behavior". May be ok or may be error. Undefined.

Comment: Add your compiler+version and what the "error" says exactly and we will be able to tell you why.

Comment: @ereOn: Setting members to NULL (because of a method call) to indicate they don't exist is OK as that will be part of the internal implementation details of the code and thus an explicit part of the state of the object. Setting objects to NULL just to try and prevent a double delete is a sign that the code is not designed correctly and can potentially do a double delete and thus needs re-factoring (It is the implementers (not the users) responsibility to make sure code can be used safely in all situations.

Comment: Once again the solution is to stop deleting things manually.

Comment: @Martin:As far as i know setting pointers to null after deleting them was always a good idea since ideally the dereferencing happens after checking if the pointer is not null.

Comment: @Samrat Patil: You have to differentiate between member that can be NULL because of state and variables that happen to be pointers. If you have a variable that is a pointer it should never be possible to reach code that uses that variable when it is NULL. Creating the object either works or throws an exception. After deleting a pointer it should be going out of scope? Thus reaching the point where a pointer variable is NULL and it is being used is a logical error. Testing before use then hides this logical error from the testers and unit tests. IMHO it is better to find the logical error.EARLY

Comment: @Martin:Totally agree! But thats ideal. I haven't encountered a practical code like that yet. Probably I should try and give some thought before writing code next time :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a VERY bad thing to do.  However C++ won't necessarily do anything here. It is "un-defined" behaviour.  That doesn't mean it will crash but it will, most probably, cause bad shit (tm) to happen.

Edit:  Furthermore in your 2nd example the fact it crashes is just a part of "undefined" behaviour.  It is undefined as to what the reaction will be.

Comment: I have voted -1 and am very sorry for that. if you just edited your post, I would be able to remove my downvote. Again, I am very sorry, my bad

Comment: @Armen:  No probs.  It happens :)

Answer (score 3):

Trust me, you don't want to do that.

Take a look at `boost::shared_ptr`: it allows you to deal with pointers in an elegant way, without having to care *too much* about their deletion.

```
class Foo {
public:
    boost::shared_ptr<int> p;
};

Foo *f1 = new Foo();
Foo *f2 = new Foo();
f1->p.reset(new int(1));
f2->p = f1->p;
delete f2; // ok
delete f1; // no error and its guaranteed !
```

If you don't want to use `boost`, some compilers already provide `std::tr1::shared_ptr` which has similar semantics.

Comment: this won't compile as is, check my code for working `f1` setup

Comment: Isn't std::tr1::shared_ptr *the* boost::shared_ptr?

Comment: @Steve Townsend: Thanks for noticing the typo. Indeed `reset()` takes a pointer.

Comment: @Mark Ingram: I wouldn't say for sure, but I believe that `std::tr1::shared_ptr` implementation depends on the compiler vendor and is not mandatorily the same than `boost`.

Answer (score 3):

> Why I did not get error when calling "delete f1"? didn't I delete the same address (*p) twice?

Yes you did delete that object twice.

However, the outcome of that is ***Undefined Behavior***. That *could* result in the run-time system catching the error and popping up a message, but it could just as well result in your HD getting formatted, nasty Nasal Demons chasing you around the office to the delight of your fellow-workers, or you or your girlfriend getting pregnant. Or then it might also appear to "work", whatever that means in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use multiple pointers to the same memory, encapsulate them in `boost::shared_ptr`, which will ensure that the underlying memory is not delete-d until the last reference to it goes out of scope.

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

class Foo {
public:
    boost::shared_ptr<int> p;
    ~Foo() {
      p.reset();
    }
};

Foo *f1 = new Foo();
Foo *f2 = new Foo();
f1->p.reset(new int(1));
f2->p = f1->p;
delete f2; // ok
delete f1; // no error
```

Comment: `p` destructor will release the pointer anyway. The explicit `~Foo` destructor is really not needed here.

Comment: @ereOn, thanks - I think this is clearer in the context of the original code.

Answer (score 0):

Of course double deletes are undefined behavior.  It is also likely to change if between debug and release builds.  Others have pointed out to you the goodness of `boost::shared_ptr` and such.

However, it is useful to also mention how you can find these kind of bugs reliably:

***Run your program in [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).***

On Windows, [purify](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/purify/) is the older, commercial counterpart to valgrind.